# Remove InputVerifier from JTextField

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, inputverifier

I'm really surprised [this is not in the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/InputVerifier.html) or [at least google](https://www.google.cz/search?q=remove%20inputverifier%20jtextfield%20java).

I have a class that is likely to need to remove the verifier or replace it with another one. In particular, these methods are defined in the interface:

```
  /**
   * Add the verifier
   */
  public void bind();
  /**
   * Remove the verifier from input
   */
  public void unbind();
```

I can implement `bind`:

```
  /**
   * Binds the events to the field using InputVerifier
   */
  @Override
  public void bind() {
    //Internal verifier
    final SettingsInputVerifier<T> verif = this.verifier;
    //Event to be called if new value is valid
    final ValueChanged<T> onchange = this.onchange;
    //Only works when you leave the field
    field.setInputVerifier(new InputVerifier() {
      @Override
      public boolean verify(JComponent in) {
        //If verification fails, return false and ignore the value
        if(!verif.verify(in))
          return false;
        //Sucessful verification means we get the value and update it
        onchange.changed(verif.value(in));
        return true;
      }
    });
  }
```

But how can I **unset** input verifier from JTextField?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way:

```
field.setInputVerifier(null);
```

Comment: In other words, if I want to replace old verifier with the new, I just call `.setInputVerifier(newverifier)`?

Comment: That's right. The new verifier replaces the old one (you can look at the code of [JComponent](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/javax/swing/JComponent.java#JComponent.setInputVerifier%28javax.swing.InputVerifier%29)) and if it is null it is removed.